# Php undefined offset error

Tags: php

Running the following code:

```
        preg_match("/^top\-sites\-csv\_(.+)\_/i", $file, $matches);
    $site_id = $matches[1];
```

And it keeps generating this notice:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset
```

I guess its happening when the regex does not find a match.
problem is that the script is on a cron and my error log grows huge in no time and then needs manual cleaning..

Comment: its like `preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);`

Comment: Add an if block to see if the array key exists, and if not, substitute something else for the site id?

Comment: You could do `if (preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches)) ` to check if there were any matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check `$matches` using [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) before working with ist:

```
if(isset($matches[1])){
  $site_id = $matches[1];
  // do more here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) did not find a match, `$matches` is an empty array. So you should check if `preg_match` found an match before accessing `$matches[1]`